# PHP postgres prepared statement doesn't recognize parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am unable to figure out the problem on my own, and hope someone can help me.

My PHP code prepares a statement if a search string is parsed to it via POST method, but postgres doesn't seem to recognise it.

I get the following error:

> bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "filtered_list_query" requires 0

Here is my code:

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM public."my_predefined_view" hwm';
    if (isset($_POST["searchfilter"])) {
      $searchstring = htmlspecialchars($_POST["searchfilter"]);
      $query .= " WHERE hwm.hostname LIKE $1";
      $query .= ' ORDER BY hwm."IP", hwm.hostname;';

      pg_prepare('filtered_list_query', $query);
      $result = pg_execute('filtered_list_query', array($searchstring))
        or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error()); 
    }
```

I really have to overlook some major error as this is basically the code from the php pg_prepare example page

EDIT:

Thank you again for your help!

As I now learned this would not have happened if I would have checked the pg_prepare like this: (of course with the wrong variable `$query`)

```
pg_prepare('filtered_list_query', $query)
  or die ('Preparation failed: ' . pg_last_error());
```

Comment: Could the problem have to do with the fact that you misspell your `$query` var and instead send in a `$querie` (undefined?) var to the prepare function?

Comment: omg... i thank you!!! (can someone please delete my question out of embarrassment?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself means that the compiler detected you want to bind a variable to your query, but it fails to locate the place where it should bind it. So basically it is not seeing the $1 place.

Single quotes are used in SQL for string literals. That means that this '$1' is just a string that contains the characters $ and 1 rather than a placeholder.

This means that your code should actually be like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM public.my_predefined_view hwm";
    if (isset($_POST["searchfilter"])) {
      $searchstring = htmlspecialchars($_POST["searchfilter"]);
      $query .= " WHERE hwm.hostname LIKE '$1'";
      $query .= ' ORDER BY hwm.IP, hwm.hostname;';

      pg_prepare('filtered_list_query', $query);
      $result = pg_execute('filtered_list_query', array($searchstring))
        or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error()); 
    }
```

Comment: Great idea, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the same error. I tried it now with just the '$1' in single quotes and the whole WHERE clause in single quotes. Nothing worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Try checking the other quotes aswel. Do you need the quotes around the view and IP?

Comment: Th doble quotes around the "IP" where necessary because otherwhise i got the error  that the column doesn't exist. (case sensivity).

Comment: Thank you again for your help, but as you can see I had a copy paste error with two variable names...